# Angular 4 with spring boot routing URL with out using hashcode

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot

Below are my scenario:

1. I am using Spring boot with Angular 4
2. I am generating build file using angular-cli and placing under resource -- static folder.
3. while run my pom.xml all the static folder is copying under target --> Project folder --> WEB-INF --> Classes --> static folder (which is expected)

Senario:

My URL's would be

https://localhost:9443/consumer
https://localhost:9443/consumer/preapproval
https://localhost:9443/consumer/preapproval/**applicant**
https://localhost:9443/consumer/preapproval/**client**

each click entire/whole URL wont be change. if i use below configuration:

`@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
}

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
}

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver defaultViewResolver() {
    return new InternalResourceViewResolver();
}
```

}`

in spring boot, when i refresh/enter any URL other than (https://localhost:9443/consumer) it is throwing 404 Error. Can any one suggest me the best solution.

Note: in my business we shouldn't use hashcode in Angular 4.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `we shouldn't use hashcode in Angular 4.` means what is the problem can you please explain it clearly

Comment: using https://localhost:9443/consumer/#/ -- we can use this but some reason management suggest us not to use '#' .

Comment: That is the reason i am try to finding other solution either from server end like Spring boot or any other solutions from Angular 4 with out using '#'.            Hope it might be clear to you

Comment: this has to be handled by server, In fact, it's normal that you have a 404 error since the actual address within the browser is updating (and without # / hashbang approach). By default, HTML5 history is used for reusing in Angular2.

If you want not having a 404 error, you need to update your server to serve the index.html file for each route path you defined.

Comment: For a work around you can check this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) the same happens when you deploy files to gh-pages and there is a workaround to it

Comment: @Rahul: do you have any examples to implement for the reference

Comment: that page itself is an example using the same if you route on that page you wont find hashes and on refresh it will not throw error.

Answer (score 0):

I set a getMapping like bellow in my project.

```
@GetMapping("/{path:[^\\.]*}")
String redirect() {
    return "forward:/";
}
```